# Bounded subset of $C^{1}[a, b]$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to know if this is a redundancy.

If $f\in C^{1}[a, b]$, $f'$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and therefore bounded on $[a, b]$. So, it would seem that any subset of $C^{1}[a, b]$ is bounded in the $C^1$ norm.

Am I correct?

Comment: The key distinction is that a collection of objects which are each bounded need not be bounded itself. Consider the similar statement: Each real number is bounded, so any set of real numbers must be bounded.

Answer (score 2):

No, I am afraid that you are not correct. Consider the set of powers $x^n$ over the interval $[0,1]$ with $n\geq 0$. This set is bounded as a subset of $C([0,1])$,
$$\|x^n\|_{C^0}=\max_{x\in[0,1]}|x^n|=1,$$
but it is not bounded as a subset of $C^1([0,1])$
$$\|x^n\|_{C^1}=\max_{x\in[0,1]}|x^n|+n\max_{x\in[0,1]}|x^{n-1}|=1+n.$$

Answer (score 0):

No. Take the set of all constant functions, for instance. If $f=k$, for some real $k$, $\lVert f\rVert_{C^1}=\lvert k\rvert$. Therefore, this set is unbounded.